# file name not displaying in the Entry line in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, filepath

I am working on a `Xamarin.Forms` app. I need to browse and open files from the folder and when i tried to do so and selected the file, the file path is not displayed in the entry line. Here is my code please let me know what should be changed?

```
public string FileName
{
    get { return fileName; }
    set
    {
        fileName = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("csv_file"));
    }
}

private Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions.FileData file = default(Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions.FileData);

public async void OnBrowse(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    this.file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
    if (this.file == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    string extensionType = this.file.FileName.Substring(this.file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) 
        + 1, this.file.FileName.Length - this.file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 1).ToLower();

    if (extensionType.Equals("csv"))
    {
        csv_file.SetValue((BindableProperty.Create("csv_file", typeof(string), typeof(Entry), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null)), fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        await this.DisplayAlert("Name of the file:" + file.FileName + " and path too file: " + file.FilePath, "File info", "OK");
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml code

```
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry x:Name="csv_file" Placeholder="" WidthRequest="150">
            </Entry>
            <Button BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="Black" 
             WidthRequest="40" Text="...." Clicked="OnBrowse"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: First, please format your code, the indentation is very messy which makes it hard to read.

Comment: Second, you should be showing us the XAMl too. Please learn how to make a [mcve]

Comment: And lastly, nowhere in this code are you setting the `FileName` property which I am *guessing* is the value your XAML is bound to?

Comment: Yes, post the xaml that goes with this, @DavidG is correct, we are just guessing. In the meantime I'm guessing that changing `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("csv_file"));` to `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FileName"));` might help.

Comment: i changed it to FileName but that did not work too ,and I posted the xaml code please check